# How to set configuration values for dll library

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, app-config

I have a wpf controls library it uses telerik components to display a ribbon window that contain a chart control. This dll is used in a mixed c++/cli library, that is used in a pure native c++ application,  The window shows first time after application run too slow, but next times show fast, I tried to fix that one thing I didn't try is to use the following configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration> 
      <runtime> 
              <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
      </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

But I has no .net executable it is native and a c++/cli library and my c# library.
Many posts I read told that library has no config file(however you can make a file for storing appsettings)
How can i set that configuration for dll?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in mylibraryname.dll.config

Comment: I added it but no difference, no evidence if the config file was used.

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 Try doing something that's easier to test. Like creating a setting with a simple value and within your dll see if that value is available and do something visible with it, like showing some MessageBox or writing it to a file.